# How can I convert hour of day and minute of hour to a datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I have a full year of data every minute:

```
dayofyear   hourofday   minuteofhour    
1            0           0  
.
.
365          23         57  
365          23         58 
365          23         59
```

I converted the `dayofyear` to a date:

`df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['dayofyear'], unit='D', origin=pd.Timestamp('2009-12-31'))`

```
    dayofyear   hourofday   minuteofhour    date
1   0   0 2010-01-01
1   0   1 2010-01-01
1   0   2 2010-01-01
1   0   3 2010-01-01
1   0   4 2010-01-01
```

How can I combine the `hourofday` and   `minuteofhour` with `date` in order to create a proper timestamp?

Like this maybe: `'2010-12-30 19:00:00'`

So that I can perform other time-filtering/subsetting etc in pandas later.

Comment: what about year? do you have a year column?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar No. I just know the  year is 2010.`

Comment: Can you share the data in a format that is easier to use? Please see: [mcve]. How are you getting the data, by the way?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the `hourofday` and `minuteofhour` columns into a TimeDelta, then add it to the `date` column:

```
df['timestamp'] = df['date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['hourofday'].astype('str') + ':' + df['minuteofhour'].astype('str') + ':00')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'dayofyear': (365, ),
    'hourofday': (23, ),
    'minuteofhour': (57, ),
})


def parse_dt(x):
    dt = datetime(2010, 1, 1) + timedelta(int(x['dayofyear']) - 1)
    dt = dt.replace(hour=x['hourofday'], minute=x['minuteofhour'])
    x['dt'] = dt
    return x


df = df.apply(parse_dt, axis=1)
print(df)

#   dayofyear  hourofday  minuteofhour                  dt
#0        365         23            57 2010-12-31 23:57:00
```

Hope this helps